# Typescript: Conditionally add items to an object

Tags: typescript

if I make an object

```
const data = {}
```

then try and add an object to it

```
const data = {};
data.shared = {};
```

I get the error `Property 'shared' does not exist on type '{}'.ts(2339)`

I add it in manually

```
const data = {
    shared: {},
};
```

and then I'm back to the same issue when I want to conditionally add a value

```
if (true) data.shared.username = 'test'
```

`Property 'username' does not exist on type '{}'.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will create an Interface to define the data structure, like this:

```
interface IData {
    shared?:{
        username?: string;
        // here any other properties you want to conditionally add
    }
}
```

in this way the compiler always know what to expect

then you can declare data as:

```
const data: IData = {}
```

Answer (score 2):

While apokyrfos's answer is correct, best practice with Typescript is to avoid `any` when possible - using the `any` type defeats the benefit of using Typescript in the first place.

What you can do is declare your object with an index signature:

```
const data: {[key: string]: SomeType} = {};
```

This way, you can assign `data.shared` at any time without an issue, as long as the type you're assigning is permitted by "SomeType" (If you have different but similar objects which may be assigned here, consider using an interface).