# "Object is possibly 'undefined'. ts(2532)" after I just defined it

Tags: typescript

TypeScript is throwing `Object is possibly 'undefined'. ts(2532)` errors for an optional parameter, even though I just defined it...

```
interface Foo {
  keyValue?: Record<string, string>
}

const a: Foo = { keyValue: { key1: 'value' } }
a.keyValue.key2 = 'value2' // Object is possibly 'undefined'. ts(2532)

const b: Foo = {}
b.keyValue = { key1: 'value' }
b.keyValue.key2 = 'value2' // Works fine
```

Why does `a.keyValue` throw the error when `b.keyValue` doesn't? The only difference is slightly more verbose syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By doing `: Foo`, you're telling TypeScript that the type that the variable contains is *exactly* `Foo` - and in `Foo`, the property is optional.

```
const a: Foo = { keyValue: { key1: 'value' } }
```

is, to TypeScript, a bit like

```
declare const a: Foo;
```

The fact that the object on the right-hand side does really have the property is lost when you say that it's actually `Foo`, where the property is optional.

But with

```
const b: Foo = {}
// at this point, b is Foo exactly
b.keyValue = { key1: 'value' }
// at this point, b is no longer exactly Foo; it also definitely has the keyValue property
```

The property is assigned *after* the variable is declared to be of type `Foo` - so TypeScript is able to see the line that assigns to the property and conclude that it definitely exists. (making the shape of `b` slightly different from the original `Foo`, where the property is optional).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Is there a better way to define a typed object to avoid these errors?

Comment: What I prefer to do is to let TS infer types automatically whenever possible (which is 97% of the time), and to create objects all at once, avoiding mutation (which makes TS auto inference easier). Doing that avoids many sorts of problems similar to the one in your question.

Comment: But if I don't type the object up-front, I can't conditionally add properties to it later: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59309133/typescript-conditionally-add-items-to-an-object

Seems like a catch-22.

Comment: Adding properties to an object when they don't already exist, for me, would be somewhat of a code smell - not only because TypeScript works better when objects are created all at once, without mutation, but also because mutated objects are (IMO) harder to reason about, in comparison with creating a new object when something's changed. But that's just my opinion, which has appeared to make TypeScript typings easy.

Comment: Adding parameters to an object when they don't already exist seems to me like a very basic building block of programming... I personally don't see how that could be considered code smell. E.g. building a `params` object to pass to a db client, where you want to conditionally add optional parameters.